# Font awesome icons and panels not showing properly when using JS

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I'm trying to create HTML elements dynamically with JS. However panels and font awesome icons are not shown properly when doing so.

This is the HTML code I want to create dynamically with JS.

```
<div class="row" id="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="panel-custom border colorized">
            <div class="fa fa-chevron-right right-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
  let row = document.getElementById('row');
  let col = document.createElement('col');
  let panelCustom = document.createElement('panel-custom');
  let fa = document.createElement('fa');

  panelCustom.classList.add("colorized");
  panelCustom.classList.add("border");
  fa.classList.add("fa-chevron-right");
  fa.classList.add("right-arrow");

  row.appendChild(col);
  col.appendChild(panelCustom);
  panelCustom.appendChild(fa);
```

Comment: There's an unclosed `<div>` in your HTML sample. Please fix it, so we can see what you intended to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this ( it should work as expected ) :

```js
let row = document.createElement('div');
row.className = "row";

let col = document.createElement('div');
col.className = "col";

let panelCustom = document.createElement('div');
panelCustom.className = "panel-custom colorized border";

let fa = document.createElement('i');
fa.className = "fa fa-chevron-right right-arrow";

panelCustom.appendChild(fa);
col.appendChild(panelCustom);
row.appendChild(col);
document.body.appendChild(row);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually create elements of type "col", "panel-custom" or "fa", like you're trying to here:

```
let col = document.createElement('col');
let panelCustom = document.createElement('panel-custom');
let fa = document.createElement('fa');
```

These are not valid HTML elements. In fact, they should be `<div>` elements as in your HTML sample. Create `<div>` elements instead:

```
let col = document.createElement('div');
let panelCustom = document.createElement('div');
let fa = document.createElement('div');
```

Then add the required classes:

```
panelCustom.classList.add("panel-custom");
panelCustom.classList.add("colorized");
panelCustom.classList.add("border");
// etc.
```